# Setting one mono within another using webflux

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive

I am retrieving a publisher `Mono<ProductOrder>` from mongo db

I have another publisher `Mono<CommandResponse>`

I want to set `ProductOrder` object into `CommandResponse` as it is a part of that class. like `commandResponse.setProductOrder(po instance)`

`CommandResponse` will also have different `Mono` or `String or Int` apart from `ProductOrder` instance

Finally want to return `Mono<ServerResponse>` which would contain body of `CommandResponse`

**i am not being able to set the `Mono<ProductOrder>` object into `Mono<CommandResponse>`**

Pleas help. Thanks.

---

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
@Component
public class Handler {


    @Autowired
    private MongoService service;

    public Mono<ServerResponse> get(ServerRequest request) {
        Mono<ProductOrder> p = service.queryById();
        
        

> Here, in the return statement i want to return Mono<CommandResponse> 
> instead of Mono<ProductOrder> in the response body
> remember: CommandResponse has a reference to ProductOrder

        return 
            ServerResponse.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(p, ProductOrder.class).map(null);
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: If you could add an actual code snippet, you'd have a better chance getting help.

Comment: added code snippet above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Mono<CommandResponse> commandMono = ... // I don't how it is set 
Mono<ProductOrder> productMono = service.queryById();
Mono.zip(commandMono, productMono)
  .map(tuple -> { 
    var command = tuple.getT1();
    var product = tuple.getT2();
    command.setProductOrder(product) // => .setProductOrder(po instance)
    return command;
  })
  .flatMap(command -> ServerResponse.ok()
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .bodyValue(command)
  )
```

I haven't run this code, so I'm not sure if it compiles, but with it you should be able to figure out how your code could work

Comment: Thanks much. @sawim